# I installed via Git-Bash Foundation Grunt Bower and Yo... Can I delete these folders and start over?

Tags: git, sass, zurb-foundation, bower, git-bash

I installed things into the wrong folder... Like my documents folder.  I believe I was supposed to just put all of these things into my project folder.

In anyevent. I would like to do it all again and just erase those folders.  Is this how you "uninstall" these things.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `git clone git@github.com:zurb/foundation.git` in the wrong folder, you could simply move that `foundation` wherever you want.

It contains the git repo (`foundation/.git`), and will work in any parent folder.

Comment: is it ok to delete it though?  I mean there is not an uninstall feature or cmd line that I need to do?

Comment: @ChristianMatthew For git, you can delete. For gems, you can uninstall first (http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/installing-and-uninstalling-gems.html#d313180e360).  Then http://foundation.zurb.com/learn/video-started-with-foundation.html

Comment: I tried to uninstall the gem... via this command line gem uninstall foundation ... I didn't notice anything came or left so then I deleted all of the folders.

Comment: the problem is that the video doesn't say where or how to put things in the folder for the various steps.

Comment: @ChristianMatthew at 2': npm install -g means it installs it in your `npm/nodes_modules` folder: it is a global installation, meaning it can be executed from anywhere.

Comment: do you have skype?  This isn't hard but the lack on instruction is not helping.  my skype is isaeruditon ... I would super appreciate it.